# Curl different outputs in Powershell and ISE

Tags: powershell

I am looking to replicate the results of a curl command from Powershell in Powershell_ISE. The command grabs a weather report for a city:

```
(curl http://wttr.in/Manchester -UserAgent "curl" ).Content
```

When I run this in powershell, it outputs a neat report that shows me information such as

```
Partly Cloudy 
24 degrees celcius 
30 KM/H Winds etc
```

When I run this in powershell_ISE, it outputs the same report but it doesnt appear to resolve the values correctly. I get

```
Partly Cloudy
38;5;226m+22[0m(38;5;226m24[0m) degrees celcius
38;5;202m30[0m KM/H Winds etc
```

Is there anything I can do to help _ISE resolve this correctly?

Any help greatly appreciated, many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The special output is ANSI Escape Sequences for coloring and formatting. In Windows it's typically called Virtual Terminal Escape Sequences.

The console host used in PowerShell ISE doesn't support it (as seen below), so you get the raw data instead of the colors.

```
> $host

Name             : Windows PowerShell ISE Host
Version          : 5.1.22000.653
InstanceId       : 09d9260c-65f0-4435-9a03-4a3aabf6bd92
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : nb-NO
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Host.ISE.ISEOptions
DebuggerEnabled  : True
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace

> $host.UI.SupportsVirtualTerminal
False
```

Nothing Windows PowerShell can do about it. The https://wttr.in API does supports a `?T` query to drop the formatting. Try:

`(curl "http://wttr.in/Manchester?T" -UserAgent "curl" ).Content`

Comment: Works a treat, thank you so much for this was driving me nuts. You have helped me out massively here in terms of understanding data scrape from APIs, how powershell and _ISE operates, etc. Thanks again!